# Print out content between a starting string and ending string and then repeat until end of string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

Suppose, I have a string str="I study at Southwestern University. I am 21. I study at Northwestern University. I am 22."

Using regular expressions, I need to print out every substring starting with "I" and ending in "University".

Output should be as follows:

"I study at Southwestern University"

"I study at Northwestern University"

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
import re

txt = "I study at Southwestern University. I am 21. I study at Northwestern University. I am 22."
# First you get the substrings with split
txt_substrings = txt.split(".")
for i in txt_substrings:
    # We need strip to delete blank spaces at the beginning of the sentence
    i = i.strip()
    dumb = re.search("^I.*University$", i)
    if dumb:
        print(f"Find substring: {i}")
```

When using the regex:

- "^": Matches the start of the string
- "$": Matches the end of the string
- ".*": Anything in between

More info in re [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Hope it helps!